# Java regex to match multiline records starting with fixed label

Tags: java, regex, multiline, records

Following is an example of a list of multiline records, each starting with a fixed string label (`LABEL`):

```
<Irrelevant line>
...
<Irrelevant line>
LABEL ...
...
...
LABEL ...
...
...
LABEL ...
...
...
LABEL ...
...
...
```

Is there a Java regular expression that can much the above and extract each record, i.e.

```
LABEL ...
...
...
```

Also, is this the fastest way of extracting those records, or reading line-by-line and checking the start of the string would yield faster results?

Comment: I would say that doing a line by line approach would be faster. Especially if the file is getting big.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but [this Ideone sample](http://ideone.com/RKWH4f) may show which is better (turns out to be startsWith).

Comment: Thanks. If you copy it as an answer, it definitely deserves +1 (or more), as do all the other answers. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over all the `LABEL` groups, use this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?sm)LABEL.*?(?=^LABEL|\\Z)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // the current LABEL group: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/42) for the various matches.

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- `LABEL` matches literal characters
- `.*?` lazily matches all chars up to...
- the point where the lookahead `(?=^LABEL|\\Z)` can assert that what follows is the next `LABEL` or the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

I think you can start with the expression:

```
^LABEL\s*\w*
```

OR

```
^LABEL.*
```

It may need some improvements but you can at least start with it.

Answer (score 1):

The below would match all the lines which starts with the string `LABEL`,

```
(?=^LABEL).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lR5lT8/4)

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view you can iterate stream per line and check if the line starts with "LABEL".

I think you can use "substring" method like

```
line.substring(0,"LABLEL".length());//you need add more checks to improve code security
```

In my point of view Regural Expressions are very useful to find pattern no a specific text.