# Java regex to match multiline sections with subsections

Tags: java, regex, record, multiline

As an expansion of a simpler `StackOverflow` [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605556/java-regex-to-match-multiline-records-starting-with-fixed-label), is there a `Java` regex that can extract in one pass each section and subsection from a multiline text document, having a structure like

```
<Irrelevant line>
...
<Irrelevant line>
####<section_title>
OVERVIEW
...
...
INTRODUCTION
...
...
DETAILS
...
...
####<section_title>
OVERVIEW
...
...
INTRODUCTION
...
...
DETAILS
...
...
```

The `section_title` can be anything and it, as well as each subsection title (OVERVIEW, INTRODUCTION, DETAILS) is the only text in the line. All other lines can contain any text, from empty to thousands of characters, in multiple lines.

Alternatively, of course, the document can be processed using a `BufferedReader` and reading line by line, but a regex would offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: Reading thousands of characters in memory and performing a regex match operation doesn't particularly sound like "a more elegant solution" to me. On a different note: how do you distinguish between subsection titles and other lines?

Comment: I'm also not sure what the question is here. What are you asking? Have you written any code?

Comment: The question is very clear. Not all questions require writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will return one sub-section at a time when iterating, optionally including the section header for the first sub-section.

```regex
(?m)(?:^####(.*)\R)?^(OVERVIEW|INTRODUCTION|DETAILS)\R(?s:(.*?))(?=^####|^(?:OVERVIEW|INTRODUCTION|DETAILS)$|\z)
```

`(?m)` means that `^` and `$` matches beginning and end of line (respectively) in the rest of the regex, so we then use `\z` to match end of input, which is what `$` normally matches.

`(?s:XXX)` makes `.` match *any* character with the `XXX` pattern, including line separator characters (`\r`, `\n`).

`\R` matches `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`, i.e. matches a line separator regardless of OS (Windows vs. Linux).

Using `.*?` (reluctant) matching followed by `(?=XXX)` will make the regex match text up to but excluding the `XXX` pattern.

*Demo*
<sub>(also available on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WqVTB2/1))</sub>

```java
String regex = "(?m)(?:^####(.*)\\R)?^(OVERVIEW|INTRODUCTION|DETAILS)\\R(?s:(.*?))(?=^####|^(?:OVERVIEW|INTRODUCTION|DETAILS)$|\\z)";

String input = "<Irrelevant line>\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "<Irrelevant line>\r\n" + 
               "####<section_title>\r\n" + 
               "OVERVIEW\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "INTRODUCTION\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "DETAILS\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "####<section_title>\r\n" + 
               "OVERVIEW\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "INTRODUCTION\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "DETAILS\r\n" + 
               "...\r\n" + 
               "...";

for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    String sectionTitle = m.group(1);
    String subSectionTitle = m.group(2);
    String content = m.group(3);
    if (sectionTitle != null)
        System.out.println("sectionTitle: " + sectionTitle);
    System.out.println("subSectionTitle: " + subSectionTitle);
    System.out.println("content: " + content.replaceAll("(?ms)(?<=.)^", "         "));
}
```

*Output*

```
sectionTitle: <section_title>
subSectionTitle: OVERVIEW
content: ...
         ...

subSectionTitle: INTRODUCTION
content: ...
         ...

subSectionTitle: DETAILS
content: ...
         ...

sectionTitle: <section_title>
subSectionTitle: OVERVIEW
content: ...
         ...

subSectionTitle: INTRODUCTION
content: ...
         ...

subSectionTitle: DETAILS
content: ...
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and the effort. +1 and accepted. :-)